# Why is my UserProperties collection empty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, interop, outlook, primary-interop-assembly

I'm using the Outlook 2003 PIA and VS 2005 to access items in a public folder.  The `item.UserProperties` collection always comes back empty, despite the items having several user defined fields.

If I add a property in code using `UserProperties.Add`, it is saved correctly with the item and is then available in the UserProperties next time the item is accessed.  However, using `MFCMapi` to access the item I can see no difference between this new property and the existing user defined ones.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How are the items getting created in the public folders, using webdav? If they get created using webdav you can't access them using item.UserProperties method, because the blob value used by the outlook doesn't get populated correctly.

[Check this link for details.](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3396626.php)

I am using a custom .Net Extended Mapi Wrapper to read this properties.

But you can always use redemption or if you are using outlook 2007 , you can access them directly.